# Recommended RAM and disc space for Oracle 11g on Windows

Tags: windows-server-2008, oracle-11g

I need to provide the recommended amount of RAM and disc space (divided in two partitions) so the customer can create an appropriate virtual machine to run Oracle. [All I could find in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24186/reqs.htm) was a brief listing with *minimum* RAM and typical/advanced install types.

The virtual machine will run latest Oracle Standard Edition One (11g release 2 so far) under Windows Server 2008 x64 and will host a reasonably low traffic web application.

How much RAM and disc must I ask for in order to be safe?

*(Feel free to ask for further details if I've omitted something relevant.)*

**Update:**

Rough estimations:

- Database size: 10 MB after installation
- Growth rate: +3MB per day on average
- Size of database 'active' data: (not sure of what this means, there's not actual archive so I guess all data is current)
- Amount of data written per second in peak hours: a few KB
- Number of client sessions: 3 or 4 at most
- Frequency and response size of most heavy requests: some reports make heavy table JOINS that need up to 20 seconds to complete but they won't return more than a few thousand rows with plain text. The app also handles BLOBs (typical size from 50KB to 200KB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capacity planning is more an art than simple calculation. You need to take into account database size, it's growth rate, size of database 'active' data, amount of data written per second in peak hours, number of client sessions, frequency and response size of most heavy requests. It is impossible to give a good advise without knowing all of it. And all the things going to change when system goes to production.

Since your requirements a very small on all parameters - give a few more than minimal requirements, 2 times more - 2GB RAM and 10GB disk space will be more than enough. Actually, if you are short on resource - give exact minimal configuration.

In a year your database will grow to about 1GB in size. I suppose you will need to revise requirements at that point.

Comment: I've done my best. It's basically a specialised internal application that will be used by a few people and only when there's work to be filed.